# facebook php sdk access users all request_ids

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Hi I have a web site and access the users by facebook application. I send users apprequests. So i want to access the users all request_ids. For example i have sent 6 messages to the current user, i know the fb user id and want to list the request_id 's.

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$user_id = "user_id is given here";
$request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
// echo "req ids: " . $request_ids."<br>";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you could include some code you might find more people are able to help you out. :-)

Comment: I've added some peace of code

Answer (score 0):

To get the requests from the user, make the call-

```
/{user-id}/apprequests
```

You will get a list of the requests and the data for each one (if any).

**Note:** The requests are accumulated and of-course cannot disappear by itself, so you need to delete the request once the user has accepted. To delete a request, make the call-

```
/{request-id}?method=delete
```